# remote.shutdown() does not kill an akka remote actor itself

Tags: scala, akka

```
object RemoteEchoServer extends App {
  remote.start("localhost", 1111)
  remote.register("hello-service", actorOf[HelloWorldActor])
}

object RemoteEchoClient extends App {
  val actor = remote.actorFor("hello-service", "localhost", 1111)
  val reply = actor !! "Hello"
  println(reply)
  actor ! "Stop"
  actor ! PoisonPill
}

/**
 * a remote actor servers for message "Hello" and response with a message "World"
 * it is silly
 */
class HelloWorldActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "Hello" =>
      println("receiving a Hello message,and a World message will rply")
      self.reply("World")
    case "Stop" =>
      println("stopping...")
      remote.shutdown()
  }
}
```

The client send a **PoisonPill** as well as a "Stop" signal ,but the remote never terminate itself. 
I must kill the remote actor in object RemoteEchoServer by invoke remote.shutdown(). How to shutdown the remote actor by receiving a "Stop" message ?

I know exit() will probably exit the server app directly, but what if there are still request needs to process.

The key point is invoking remote.shutdown() never shutdown the remote service(server app), so what should i do if i want to stop the server app for the actor

Comment: I'm wondering why this was voted to close?!

Comment: Why do you want to shut down the entire remoting service just to shut one actor down?

Comment: And you can't send the PoisonPill _after_ the stop message, since you can't be sure that the remoting is still working when you send the PoisonPill (which is going to be sent by remote)

Comment: Also, I note that you haven't started the remoting service on your client.

Comment: this example app was inspired by the example akka documentation, the client is not needed to start, it is just the delegate for the remote actor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An actor can kill itself by invoking `self.stop`. So forget the PoisonPill and just use the `Stop` message:

```
case "Stop" => {
  println("stopping...")
  self.stop
  remote.shutdown()
}
```

Comment: A sensible alternative is to override "def postStop" and shut the remoting down there, and then you can just reuse the PoisonPill message instead of creating your own "Stop" message.

Comment: i tried this way, but the server app never terminate after the whole program finish, it seems the server are still waiting for accept remote connections

Comment: Weird. I am sure I used it that way. What I noticed, is that sometimes the termination can take a couple of minutes. Have you tried waiting a bit ?

Comment: That is too long time. If i call remote.shutdown() in RemoteEchoServer the server app will terminate immediately. So.... what a strange behavior .......